# Working of scala actors in the context on collaborative editor exampe

Tags: scala, actor

What would be the part of actors in scala in the case of online collaborative editor? For example if I am trying to make an appliation similar to google docs where people can share documents online and edit them concurrently.How actors work in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Read about operational transformation first.

- http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/understanding-and-applying-operational-transformation
- http://ot.substance.io/visualization/